# vis graph2d library cut the "y-axis-right" range

Tags: javascript, vis-timeline

in vis graph2d,
when I config two axises that way:

```
dataAxis: {
        left: { range: { min: 0, max: 100 } },
        right: { range: { min:0, max:280 } },
    }
```

vis library cut me the right range, and set the range of right axis to 200.
So every time that vis do not success to match the right range to the left range.

Anyone know a way to get over this?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function that cut the right range:

DataScale.prototype.followScale

I write "return;" at line 1 of this function,

and this bug is resolved.